# Wifi connection works but can't connect to internet

Tags: configuration, slackware, wpa-supplicant

I've recently switched to using Slackware 14 on my laptop, so far I'm quite happy with the distro, except for 1 *really* annoying little thing: I can surf using hotspots, and all sorts of public wifi-access-points, but I can't seem to get on-line at home.

Prior to running Slackware, I was using Debian, so yes, my laptop has been on my home network, without mac-spoofing or anything. 
Currently, I've setup my wlan interface as `eth1`, and added these lines in my `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -ieth1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Which does the trick, it seems, using something like `wpa_cli` or `wpa_gui`, I can easily connect to my home network. 
I therefore changed the wpa_supplicant file a bit, adding:

```
network={
    ssid="HomeSweetHome"
    psk=0123464sdasd4d56agr6 #output from wpa_passpharse HomeSweetHome mypassphrase
    key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK #and so on
}
```

But no matter what I do (use settings above, or connect manually) I can connect to other machines on the LAN, but as soon as I try to google something, nothing happens. Constantly "Waiting for siteX" is all I get.

Does anybody here have any idea as to what I'm missing here? There *has* to be something I haven't configured as supposed to here... I can't think of anything ATM, though.

*Update:*

Yes, I can `ping 8.8.8.8`, no problem. I can add network locations and share files with the other computers in the network, too.

Output of `ifconfig eth1`:

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::213:ceff:fef1:5267  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:13:ce:f1:52:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 491  bytes 57950 (56.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75  bytes 10228 (9.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  base 0x6000  memory 0xdfcff000-dfcfffff
```

Output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 eth1
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 eth1
```

`ping google.com`: All went well, 0% packet loss, on average 20ms/packet.

`tcptraceroute` isn't installed at the moment, but I'll set it up in due time. For now, here's the output of `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  1.190 ms  1.872 ms  5.465ms
 2  192.168.0.1  5.520 ms  5.699 ms  6.960 ms
 3  78.21.0.1  15.007 ms  15.850 ms  17.525 ms
 4  * * * *
 5  213.224.253.9  27.151 ms  28.096 ms  28.146 ms
    # And so on, all the way to:
12  * * * *
13  8.8.8.8  17.921 ms  22678 ms  20.022 ms
```

Comment: When at home, after connecting to wifi, (1) Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? (2) Post output if `ifconfig` (3) Post output of `route -n`

Comment: @JohnSiu: added additional info

Comment: One more question, can you `ping google.com`?

Comment: Please post the output of `tcptraceroute google.com 80`, or if you can't easily install tcptraceroute then at least `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: @JohnSiu: Ping google works just fine, added abbreviated output of `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` to the question, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added:

```
network={
    ssid="HomeSweetHome"
    psk=0123464sdasd4d56agr6
    key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK #and so on
}
```

To the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, what I should've done is just add the raw output of `wpa_passphrase HomeSweetHome mypasspharse` to the file, not bothering with manually adding settings like `key_mgmt` and others. Everything is working just fine with this:

```
network={
    ssid="HomeSweetHome"
    # psk="mypassphrase"
    psk=0123464sdasd4d56agr6
}
```